# How to get a created event's details using the Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have created an event on Facebook using the JavaScript SDK. Now I want to get the details of that event. How can I get it?

And also I want to get all the events created by a user?

Answer (score 1):

To get event details:

```
FB.api('/YOUR_EVENT_ID', function(data) {
  console.log(data) 
});
```

As far as I know it's not possible to get events created by a specific user directly. But you can fetch all events related to a user. If you request fields=owner you'll get an owner field attached to the event which you can use to filter by creator/owner.

```
FB.api('/me/events?fields=owner', function(data) { 
  console.log(data)
})
```